# I want to catch only update,insert and delete operation of Contacts when onChange is called. How can i do it ...?

Tags: android

I have following code.

```
public class TestContentObserver extends Activity {
    int contactCount = 0;
    final String[] projection = new String[] { RawContacts.CONTACT_ID, RawContacts.DELETED };
    Cursor curval;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        curval = getContentResolver().query(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
        contactCount = curval.getCount();

        curval.registerContentObserver(new ContentObserver(new Handler()) {
            @Override
            public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
                getChangedContactDetails();
            }
            @Override
            public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
                return true;
            }
        });

    }



    public void getChangedContactDetails(){
        // how can I catch the affected contact details
    }
}
```

when i make a call from contacts it also goes to onChange function. But i want to take only insert,update and delete of contacts. Please can you help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is a trick question, you need to understand how contacts actually work before you do this. Each contact is associated with an Account and hence whenever there is a change in contact (outside that Account), it is marked dirty. You can fetch all these contacts using this dirty flag. But if the contacts are actually changed by the Account itself, then this flag will not be set.

If you are not sure what I am talking about and you don't care which account the contacts belongs too then the ideal way would be to keep a contact id and version reference in your app somewhere. In this function of yours query all the contacts and iterate through the list

1. Check if there is a new contact which you can't find in your reference table. It is an newly added contact.
2. Check if the version is higher now, it is an updated contact
3. Check if the contact is missing (which you had in your table previously) it has been deleted.

If you don't use Account Manager, you have no option but to go through this cycle.

Comment: Thank for your reply.

But I dont need to identify which record modified. I want to know only modification occured in contacts only. When I use content observer onchange method is called with passing parameter value of false. So i can catch that event. but the issue is when i make a call from contact at that time also it call to onChange function.